# Html.Action Puts nothing to the page ( WebView Syntax )

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I use Html.Action in webview syntax, it puts nothing to the page. I see it goes to the Navigation controller of the TopMenu action when I debug without any problem, but nothing appears to the page. Am I missing something ?

```
//I USE THIS ON MASTERPAGE
<% Html.Action("TopMenu", "Navigation"); %>


//IN CONTROLLER
public class NavigationController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult TopMenu()
    {
        return PartialView("TopMenu");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the main view and TopMenu partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this:

```
<%= Html.Action("TopMenu", "Navigation") %>
```

instead of:

```
<% Html.Action("TopMenu", "Navigation") %>
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>You're using razor incorrectly.</s> Instead of putting your code on a code block, you should use the <s>@</s> syntax in your view like so:

```
<%= Html.Action("TopMenu", "Navigation") %>
```

Or if you still want to use a codeblock, you can do Html.RenderAction helper instead. And that would write directly to the buffer(it's a little bit more efficient as well)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with Razor.

Comment: Downvote? It's the same principle, hes using a code block instead of an expression, whether he's using razor or not is irrelevant actually

Comment: But that's not what your answer says. Your answer says "you're using razor incorrectly," which is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Jesus christ, there you go, happy? Could have edited the answer and made something useful instead of complaining and down voting

Comment: The downvote button is there for a reason. You should address your attitude.